# How to declare global variable in C?

Tags: c, global-variables

I am starting to use C. I have problem to define global variable. E.g. `platformID` is used in `install.c`. I declared in `main.c` but still I got error :

```
install.c|64|error: 'platformID' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

**main.c:**

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif

 cl_int err;//the openCL error code/s
 cl_platform_id platformID;//will hold the ID of the openCL available platform
 cl_uint platformsN;//will hold the number of openCL available platforms on the machine
 cl_device_id deviceID;//will hold the ID of the openCL device
 cl_uint devicesN; //will hold the number of OpenCL devices in the system

#include "include/types.h"
#include "include/gaussian.h"
#include "include/args.h"
#include "include/files.h"
#include "refu/Time/rfc_timer.h"
#include <stdio.h>
```

...

**install.c**

```
#include "include/types.h"
#include "include/gaussian.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include <sys/types.h> // mkdir
#include <sys/stat.h> // mkdir

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif

#define MAX_SOURCE_SIZE (1048576) //1 MB
#define MAX_LOG_SIZE    (1048576) //1 MB

// Install: build kernel
bool buildKernels(char ** path,FILES * files, int count )
{

    int c; // number of file

    if(clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platformID, &platformsN) != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Could not get the OpenCL Platform IDs\n");
        return false;
    }
    if(clGetDeviceIDs(platformID, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT, 1,&deviceID, &devicesN) != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Could not get the system's OpenCL device\n");
        return false;
    }
```

...

How to declare the global variable so it is visible in the included file? Can you help to fix it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
/* a.h */
extern int globali;  /* Declaration for compilation */
/* Visible here */
```

Later make sure you define in (exactly) one of the compilation units.

```
/* something.c */
int globali = 42;  /* Definition for linking */
```

Comment: Thanks. You have typo in variable name. I placed the declarations in the included c file and it works. If I move it to the included header should I also move this? `#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif
` to the header? This includes the types which I use there.

Answer (score 3):

Use extern before using that variable in the install.c. After that compile the both the files at same time.

```
extern cl_platform_id platformID;
```

Answer (score 2):

Add one line

```
extern cl_platform_id platformID;
```

before referring to `platformID` in install.c.

Answer (score 2):

add this in install.c before using that variable

```
 // external declaration for compilation
 extern cl_platform_id platformID; // It is defined in main.c file
```